# Excel question combing text with numbers

Tags: excel

Can someone tell me how I can make the following output?

I have a cell with a number for example:

- 12345 (a1)

I have a path to a file:

- ../dir/dir2/dir3

and a file extension called .jpg

I need a output in f3 like this

- ../dir/dir2/dir3/12345.jpg

I tried a lot of stuff like:

- ../dir/dir2/dir3+A1 (I know, I can't count text and numbers)

So I tried the following

- ../dir/dir2/dir3&A1

But nothing seems to work

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
="../dir/dir2/dir3" & A1
```

Work?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the "" I found this example: =A2&" sold "&B2&" units."

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following formula:
`=concantenate("../dir/dir2/dir3"),a1,".jpg")`, where everything between the quotes needs to be the entire path.